# How to read / write to PostgreSQL multiple CSV files (with various headers data) using Java

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, csv

I have about 10 types of CSV files. Each of them has got different header (row) data structure. Is it any way to store them in PostgreSQL and then read in frontend? I've done some reasearch and found opencsv but I guess that it's not full solution of problem.

Comment: *"Is it any way ... ?"* Yes. --- Now read: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273/202153)

Comment: You can try https://poi.apache.org/

Comment: What you have to do is to map your `csv` files to your `table` in the database. OpenCSV should help. Everything you mentioned above is possible. I guess you don't know how to design your program ?